# Mac - multiple windows or multiple views?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am new to developing on for Mac. I have the following scenario:

A Login window with login button. when user presses login button, the main program view should appear.

The question is should i have LoginWindow that disappears once login clicked and OtherWindow that appears. Or, should i have one MainWindow with LoginView and OtheView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you should simply open your main window and then ask the user for his/her credentials in a modal view. You can find the [Apple docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Tasks/UsingAppModalDialogs.html). Look also at how Mail.app does it, if you like.

Even better would be letting the user define credentials in a preference pane; the modal view will also come at hand in this case, if the user set the wrong credentials, e.g.